# Pandas Multi index Comparison and Relative Difference

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please tell me how i can get the relative difference between multi-index categories.
In the example below i m trying to find the difference in percentage between PC==5 and PC==6 for each hull_area element.

[image]

To demonstate in excel is the green column that i m trying to calculate
[image]

Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: please share your data & expected output as text, not screenshot images

Comment: Hi Ali, is it actually possible to upload files in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(df.loc[5] - df.loc[6]) / df.loc[6]
```